# Use httpclient to click next button?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am writing a program to scrape the source code off a website. Each time the next button is clicked to go to the next page on the website a post request it sent.

I have been looking at using httpclient to take care of this issue, and have looked through examples and the httpclient API, but I cant seem to figure out whether httpclient can do this. Is this a function of httpclient, and if so what class would go about doing this?

Comment: maybe you should have a look at jsoup http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsoup/info

Comment: HttpClient is very capable of doing this, but you will need to code it. The button will, likely, be wrapped in a form tag, which provides the method and URL of the form is to submitted to the server, in your example, this is a post. You need to form a Post command, wrap the required form parameters with it and then execute the command

Comment: @FredericClose I have briefly looked into jsoup, do you think this would be better for this kinda of program?

Comment: Can you provide an example url for the page containing the "next" button?

Comment: @axiopisty  It would be this website:
http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/SheriffSearch/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dSaleDate%26searchString%3d10%2f15%2f2013%26foreclosureType%3d%27NONT%27%2c+%27PAR%27%2c+%27COMM%27%2c+%27TXLN%27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're saying the webpage you're performing an http get on contains a "next button" on it, and that when you view the webpage in the browser and click the next button, the next page of the website is displayed.

If this is the case, yes, http client is able to do the same thing. But understand that http client does not integrate with your web browser. But you could scour the source code returned from the http get request using a library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to extract the url for the "next" page on the website, and then issue another http get to get that resource.

Assuming you already have the code for http client to issue the initial http get request, there is no additional api that is required. You just make another request after your program discovers the url for the "next" resource.

Comment: I have a program that runs well using URLConnection, so may it just be better to integrate jsoup into that program to receive all the urls?

Comment: That is certainly an option. If you review the link in my answer for jsoup, there is a simple example how to use jsoup on the homepage. Jsoup is a very powerful, and if you're familiar with css, intuitive and easy to use library! :)